# Find the least number of muffins baked

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

**This question appeared in Aryabhatta Inter School Maths Competition 2020**

> Tejaswini is baking muffins. When she packs 3 muffins in a box, 2
> muffins are left. If she packs 5 muffins in a box, 3 muffins are left.
> When she packs 7 muffins in a box, she is left with as many muffins as
> were left when she packed 5 muffins. What was the least number of
> muffins she baked ?

Answer is  : 38

Comment: Context would require more than source. For example , do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: What was the least number of muffins she baked? How to solve this one sir

Comment: Ok, so in relation to the question you are asking : do you know the Chinese Remainder theorem? The question looks at a number and its remainders when divided by $3,5,7$, and asks you to guess the number. This comes under the Chinese remainder theorem. If you wish you can brute force by considering numbers which satisfy one of the conditions, then you keep moving till you satisfy the other three.

Comment: If you didn't have the condition about three muffins in a box, could you answer that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can also be solved using **Euclid's division lemma**, as follows:

By the given conditions, we can express the total number of muffins $K$ as, $$K=3a+2=5b+3=7c+3$$ where $a,b,c$ are the number of boxes packed fully.

Hence, $$K-3=5b=7c$$ which means that $K-3$ is a multiple of both $5$ and $7$. The smallest number to exhibit this property is obviously: $$LCM(5,7)=35$$ Hence, $$K-3=35 \implies K=38$$ However, we cannot be sure it is a correct answer until and unless it satisfies the other condition too, now $$38=3(12)+2$$ Hence, our answer is $
38$.

Comment: I have another question posted (can u ps help)  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134731/how-many-customers-visited-the-shop-on-the-opening-day-and-how-many-different-gi